# how do I persist a session in a mixed Apache and Tomcat environment

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, spring-security, jsessionid

I have Apache to serve static content and Tomcat for dynamic content, linked by mod_jk. My application is Spring based, using Spring Security.  The Apache pages are port 80, the Tomcat pages are servered on port 8080. I find that Spring Security properly invokes the logon and a JSESSIONID cookie is created. This JSESSIONID cookie persists while I continue to navigate to pages that are dynamic; that is, to pages that are served up by Tomcat. When I navigate to a static page, the JSESSIONID cookie disappears. Presumably this means that the Tomcat session has ended. This means that when I subsequently navigate back to a dynamic page, Spring Security requires that I logon again.
How can I persist Spring Security in a mixed static and dynamic environment of this sort? Is there any way to have the JSESSIONID cookie persist when I navigate back to a page served by Apache.

The JSESSIONID is created when I first access the dynamic pages (when I do the login through spring-security). The JSESSIONID remains present and unchanged while I navigate through any dynamic pages (that is, through pages that are served up by Tomcat). When I navigate to a static page the JSESSIONID cookie disappears (it's not a question of its value changing - there is no JSESSIONID cookie present).
Worker Properties is:

```
worker.list=ajp13_worker
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13_worker.lbfactor=50
worker.ajp13_worker.cachesize=10
worker.ajp13_worker.cache_timeout=600
worker.ajp13_worker.socket_keepalive=1
worker.ajp13_worker.socket_timeout=300
```

Configuration directives are:

```
JkMount /OLOSmember/ ajp13_worker
JkMount /OLOSmember/* ajp13_worker
```

Browser is Chrome. Apache and Tomcat7 are on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question to give a definitive answer. Here are some things you can do to troubleshoot.

- Use firebug to see if the jsessionid is being sent when you are navigating to a dynamic pages form the static pages. Does firebug show the value of the JSESSION id changing, you want to isolate the layer that the problem is in, is the jsession id making it to apache but not getting passed tomcat or not?
- show your mod_jk configuration directives and the worker.properties files for tomcat that way we can better help you.

Comment: The JSESSIONID is created when I first access the dynamic pages (when I do the login through spring-security). The JSESSIONID remains present and unchanged while I navigate through any dynamic pages (that is, through pages that are served up by Tomcat). When I navigate to a static page the JSESSIONID cookie disappears (it's not a question of its value changing - there is no JSESSIONID cookie present).
Worker Properties is:

Comment: This was my error. In fact, the code is working. JSESSIONID is persisted and the security works properly. I was misled because Chrome Inspect shows the cookie as "disappearing" when you navigate back to the static content. In fact, it doesn't disapear - Chrome just stops showing it because it is not assocated with the static page that is displayed.
It also works fine if you use mod_proxy rather than mod_jk.